# Is it possible to access the real database from another application?

Tags: android, realm

Is it possible that another application installed on the device can access the realm database of my app?.some form of accessing the database without going through the application?

Comment: Yes?
Try [these tips](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get more, better, and faster answers.

Comment: What about using a  content provider? This may be what you want. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43485746/realm-with-content-provider?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your definition of "through the app".
You can expose a DB in many ways, but there is always an owning app associated.

You could do any of the following:

1. Build a service app that owns the DB and allow access via service binding
2. Build a ContentProvider for the app that owns the DB and allow access via URL and set the security in the manifest for exposing access
3. Use a private flat file database and set it up for shared access to other applications, and grant specific applications permission to read/write that directory. This is required whenever you pass a file to another app already, but probably not what you are looking for.

I would recommend going with number 2, it's the most straight forward and used often.

But if you just want direct access to open the DB, read,write, and basic CRUD operations, then our only option is to share out that specific directory and access the Database by loading it at runtime from the file system from any app that would use it. It's doable, but a bit messy if you ask me. I would rather an owner app provide access via a content provider personally.

Goodluck.